# In Oracle (PL/SQL), what is the most efficient way of identifying words in a regular expression?

Tags: regex, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

Edit: I should have been specific, I need to do this within PL/SQL, more specifically within functions/procedures within a package.

I have a routine that will process many (10s of millions) clobs looking for words and phrases. The routine is currently optimized by removing most special characters and using space as the delimiter of choice. It has become obvious that I need to include at least a subset of special characters to make the text more readable, post processing. That subset is;

```
()*+./
```

I am starting to rewrite the routines. My first bit of code is to be able to count the words, and this is what I came up with;

```
SELECT REGEXP_COUNT(REGEXP_REPLACE('THIS IS (A TEST) OF/SPECIAL 20.5 SOME+ODD CHARACTERS.','(\(|\)|\*|\+|\. |\/)',' '),'[^ ]+') 
FROM DUAL;
```

I have not run benchmarks on this but I suspect it is fairly inefficient. Is there a better way?

I will also need to use regexp_replace, and regexp_substring in my code. My existing code does this;

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_SUBSTR(TEMP_TEXT,'[^ ]+',1,ORDINAL_POSITION),'(\.$|^\(|\)$)','')
UPPER(REGEXP_SUBSTR(TERM,'[^ ]+',1,CURRENT_COUNT))
```

Notice the previous code actually handled "." and partially handled "/".

Comment: Hi,What is that routine which is looking for words and phrases. I think  we can make use of Oracle Full text Search for this. It will remove most of the special characters implicitly we can add our own stop words too.

Comment: The routine(s) I created reads text, searching for specific words and phrases, counts them, makes decisions on them and then annotates them writing the annotated text to a separate area. The overall purpose is to scan medical text and extract meaningful data from the text.

Comment: Then, I Reckon, oracle full text search would be efficient.

Comment: Praneeth, I will look into Oracle Full text search. However I have somewhat simplified what I am doing. There are well in excess of 15,000 terms/phrases that I need to search for in a single clob. There are 5 Clobs per record and currently > 10,000,000 records. Then I need to look for negation of the terms/phrases. Once done with that I have additional searches across each of the clobs with smaller term tables.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered treating this like a lexer instead of a collection of string functions?  It might be better to handle things one-character-at-a-time.

Building a finite automata is more work but will give you more control and will be faster than regular expressions.  It will also help you think more clearly about your problem.  For example, it will make you realize that identifying "what is a space" is not a trivial problem, and many tools do it differently.

The regular expression approach may not work for real CLOBs.  PL/SQL functions will implicitly convert CLOBs to VARCHAR2 when possible.  Everything may work fine until you test a string over 32,767 bytes.  Then the conversion may throw an error, truncate text, or return the wrong characters.

---

Unfortunately it is not trivial to convert a CLOB into a table of characters.

If your database character set is UTF8, CLOBs will use UCS.  The difference between UTF8 and UCS is normally irrelevant because the implicit conversion between CLOBs and VARCHAR2 handles it perfectly.  But when you're forced to use DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR you may discover a difficult problem - what we normally consider "one character" may be "two characters" in a CLOB.

For example, consider this code:

```
declare
  --The "cut" character in Cantonese.  Looks like a person with a sword.
  v_4_byte_utf8 varchar2(1 char) := unistr('\d841\df79');
  v_string varchar2(10 char) := v_4_byte_utf8||v_4_byte_utf8||v_4_byte_utf8;
  v_clob clob := v_string;
begin
  dbms_output.put_line('Whole string: '||v_clob);
  dbms_output.put_line('First character: '||substrc(v_clob, 1, 1));
  dbms_output.put_line('First character: '||dbms_lob.substr(v_clob, amount=>1, offset=>1));
end;
/

Whole string: 
First character: 
ORA-22923: amount of data specified in streaming LOB write is 0
```

The third output generates an error because the first "character" has two UCS code units, so grabbing an amount of 1 doesn't make sense.  Likewise you wouldn't want to start from the wrong code unit.

Oracle can detect problems when starting from 1, or starting from a bad spot in a string.  But unfortunately it does not always throw an error if you *end* in a bad spot.  The code has to do a look-ahead, starting on the end spot, and if there's an error adjust it by one.

This seems like madness - Oracle really expects us to know exactly what is in the CLOBs before we retrieve data from them?  I hope I'm wrong, but until someone shows me a better way, this function is what I use to convert CLOBs to characters.

```
create or replace type varchar2_table is table of varchar2(1 char);

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--Create a nested table of characters.
--This extra step takes care of non-trivial Unicode processing up front.
--This cannot be simplified with SUBSTRC, that will not work for large CLOBs.
--TODO: Is there an easier way to do this?
create or replace function get_varchar2_table_from_clob(p_clob clob) return varchar2_table
is
    v_varchar2 varchar2(32767 byte);

    v_chars varchar2_table := varchar2_table();

    v_offset_not_on_char_boundary exception;
    pragma exception_init(v_offset_not_on_char_boundary, -22831);

    v_next_char_boundary number := 1;
    v_amount_to_read constant number := 8000;
begin
    --Return empty collection is there's nothing.
    if p_clob is null then
        return v_chars;
    --Convert CLOB to VARCHAR2 the easy way if it's small enough.
    elsif dbms_lob.getLength(p_clob) <= 8191 then
        v_varchar2 := p_clob;
        for i in 1 .. lengthc(v_varchar2) loop
            v_chars.extend();
            v_chars(v_chars.count) := substrc(v_varchar2, i, 1);
        end loop;
    --Convert CLOB to VARCHAR2 the hard way if it's too large.
    else
        --Convert multiple characters from CLOB to VARCHAR2 at once.
        --This is tricky because CLOBs use UCS and VARCHARs use UTF8.
        --Some single-characters in VARCHAR2 use 2 UCS code points.
        --They can be treated as 2 separate characters but must be selected together.
        --Oracle will not throw an error if SUBSTR reads half a character at the end.
        --But it does error if it starts at a bad character.
        --The code below finds the valid character boundary first, and then reads up to it.
        for i in 1 .. ceil(dbms_lob.getLength(p_clob)/v_amount_to_read) loop
            begin
                --Check if the next boundary is OK by trying to read a small amount.
                --TODO: Checking 2 bytes is as expensive as retrieving all data.  Pre-fetch and use later if valid?
                v_varchar2 := dbms_lob.substr(lob_loc => p_clob, offset => v_next_char_boundary + v_amount_to_read, amount => 2);

                --If it's ok, grab the data and increment the character boundary.
                v_varchar2 := dbms_lob.substr(lob_loc => p_clob, offset => v_next_char_boundary, amount => v_amount_to_read);
                v_next_char_boundary := v_next_char_boundary + v_amount_to_read;

            --If it wasn't successful, grab one less character and set character boundary to one less.
            exception when v_offset_not_on_char_boundary then
                v_varchar2 := dbms_lob.substr(lob_loc => p_clob, offset => v_next_char_boundary, amount => v_amount_to_read - 1);
                v_next_char_boundary := v_next_char_boundary + v_amount_to_read - 1;
            end;

            --Loop through VARCHAR2 and convert it to array.
            for i in 1 .. lengthc(v_varchar2) loop
                v_chars.extend();
                v_chars(v_chars.count) := substrc(v_varchar2, i, 1);
            end loop;
        end loop;
    end if;

    return v_chars;

end get_varchar2_table_from_clob;
/
```

Things become much more sane when you can deal with things one-character-at-a-time.

That function is from my open source project [plsql_lexer](https://github.com/method5/plsql_lexer), which might also be helpful if you want to create a lexer/scanner instead of just regular expressions.